# Open-source libraries for voice-chat using JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, flash

I am looking for a way to implement voice-chat in my site using PHP and JavaScript. Is there any open-source libraries that could be used for this. I would also use Flash if required, but I can't use anything else than Flash, JavaScript or PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to try http://www.webrtc.org? Interesting thing,up to know I thought Flash would be necessary for things like this...